# How to import sample codename one demos in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone

I have downloaded the official codename one demos from here : https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos

I opened one of the projects ( such as KitchenSink or Dr.Sbaitso ) in IntelliJ by going to File-> Open -> Selecting a project folder (KitchenSink).

I get the following error if I try to run the project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Do I need to add some library files?Please share the process. Also, is there a way to automate this step(adding libraries) whenever we open a codename one project? For example, If I import an existing Android project, IntelliJ/Android Studio automatically configures it. 
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a new project with that name. Then copying the code from the demo. This will provide the libraries necessary to compile and the IntelliJ specific files.

Ideally we'll make this process simpler like we did on Eclipse/NetBeans but we currently don't have a dedicated IDEA plugin developer on staff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any 'feature request ' thread where it can be added for future consideration?

Comment: There is an issue tracker in the github project

Comment: I @ShaiAlmog, I started using condenameone, I have used the Android Studio to develop for android only using linux, but now, I need to migrate my projects to others platforms, then I try to install the codenameone in studio but don't work, so I noticed that it only work in netbeans an IntelliJ. I installed the IntelliJ here, so at now these problem has solved?
thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question?